# windows batch file: calling executable in another directory

Tags: windows-vista, batch-file

This seems like something simple, but I don't seem to be able to get it.
I have a directory called "test" with an executable hello.exe that basically prints "hello" onto the screen.

I want to execute this program from the current directory using relative paths.
So I write

```
test\hello.exe
```

Thinking it would execute the program "hello.exe" located in directory "test". But it doesn't. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is your current directory? "But it doesn't", so what does it do when you run the command?

Comment: @zxt, I was in a directory called, say, "base" that contains the folder "test". I would try to call the exe while I'm in "base", but nothing happens when I type in test\hello.exe

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following in the batch file:

```
%~dp0test\hello.exe
```

The "%~dp0" is a variable that gets replaced with the full path of the batch file, so that it should work even if you don't set the current directory of the batch file.

Comment: Wonderful, that did the trick. I"m guessing cmd line doesn't like relative paths?